# Почему в "вытанцовывать" -- о, а в "заночёвывать" -- ё

Tags: морфология

> вытанц**о**вывать,  заноч**ё**вывать

Как объяснить, что в первом слове гласная **о**, а в другом -- **ё**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Буква Ё после Ц под ударением не пишется никогда, в отличие от буквы Ё после шипящих, в том числе твердых Ж, Ш.

Это связано с тем, что после шипящих буква Ё в обязательном порядке пишется в окончаниях глаголов и суффиксах причастий и отглагольных прилагательных (стрижёт, печёт, тушёный, зажжённый). Это общее свойство всех глаголов: даже если основа твердая (несу), то перед звуком О происходит чередование с мягким согласным (несешь). Поэтому мы можем сохранить букву Ё и в глагольном суффиксе для единообразного написания глаголов: заночёвывать, растушёвывать (сравнить: размалёвывать).

Но основа на Ц в глаголах не встречается, поэтому форма "вытанцёвывать" будет нежелательным прецедентом.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы не согласная "ц", которая не записывается с "ё" (видимо, потому, что в любом слоге звучит твёрдо), то "ё" в обоих случаях пригодилось бы для сохранения единообразия с родственными словами, напр. имеющими безударное "е" в другом варианте глагольного суффикса (заноч**е**вать).

Answer (score 0):

Буква "Ц" , как "ж, ш" относится к непарным твердым согласным. И подобно тому, как буква " ш, Ш не допускают после себя написания буквы "ы", так буква " ц" не допускает написания " Ё": 
Цоколь, пританцовывать, но танцевать ( " е" - безударное)